# Make UILabel at 45 degree with a cross background colour swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

I want to display a text at 45 degree with a background color.

Example

[image: like this]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what you have attempted?

Comment: For rotation you can use `CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45)` and for background use `UIBezierPath`. But you should try first and if you face a particular issue then you should ask here with the relevant code.

Comment: I managed to rotate the label but can't got the color

Comment: for filling color try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/32547886/5069429

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This element contains two sub-elements:

1. triangle `UIView`;
2. rotated `UILabel`.

First can be achieved by creating custom view with override `draw` method:

```
class TriangleView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.maxY))
        path.close()

        UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5).setFill()
        path.fill()
    }

}
```

The second is simple transform rotation for -45 degree:

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi / 4)
```

Result:

[image]

Next thing you should manage – precisely set `UILabel` bounds (label shouldn't go away from the screen) and lines count. Constraints and attributed inspector for `UILabel` element can help you.