# Not able to draw custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

i am trying create triangle like custom view but it is not showing. i am not getting what is the wrong

i am referring this [Make UILabel at 45 degree with a cross background colour swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50425299/make-uilabel-at-45-degree-with-a-cross-background-colour-swift)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
let triangleView = TriangleView()
        triangleView.draw(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        testView.addSubview(triangleView)
    }
}

class TriangleView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
                let path = UIBezierPath()
                path.move(to: .zero)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.maxY))
               path.close()
                 UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(1).setFill()
                path.fill()
    }

}
```

want to create custom view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call draw() method explicitly. Just set the frame for the triangle view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let customView = TriangleView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    testView.addSubview(customView)
}
```

Hope it helps!!!